# Boolean function from incomplete truth table

Tags: boolean-computation

BooleanFunction in mathematica can convert an input truth table to a Boolean function. It can do so even if the truth table is incomplete. But the interpretation of truth table obtained from such an incomplete truth table is not clear.

For example, let the incomplete truth table be:

```
A  B  C
0  0  0
0  1  0
1  0  1
```

The output Boolean function is C=A in this case.

But if the truth table is

```
A  B  C
0  0  0 
0  1  1 
1  0  0
```

Then the output truth table is C= !A & B, instead of C=B

The code for generating Boolean function from first truth tables is as follows:

```
BooleanFunction[{{False, False}->False,{False,True}->False,{True,False}->True},{A,B}];
```

For the second truth table, it is

```
BooleanFunction[{{False, False}->False,{False,True}->True,{True,False}->False},{A,B}];
```

Can anyone help in giving consistent explanation for above results? The algorithm used in BooleanFunction is not clear.

Comment: Can you add the working *Mathematica* code associated with these truth tables and operations?

Comment: Have edited the question to include the code, thanks.

Comment: The code is not complete. What are the definitions of `arr` and `inputs`?

Comment: That part is just to read the input text file, specify (A,B) as input and C and output values.

Comment: Please add all necessary definitions.

Comment: Have edited out unnecessary parts for clarity.

Comment: Nowhere does it say the output of `BooleanFunction` on an incomplete table will be minimal. Either supply the remaining state or reverse the variables.

Comment: yup, but which among the several possible rules is the actual output, is the issue. How are the not provided values treated.

Comment: You sure using `C` doesn't cause problems? Try using lower case letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `BooleanMinterms` to solve the system:

1st

```
table1 = {{0, 0} -> 0, {0, 1} -> 0, {1, 0} -> 1};
trueTab1 = Pick[table1, table1[[All, 2]], 1];
boolMin1 = BooleanMinterms[trueTab1[[All, 1]], {a, b}]

(* a && ! b *)
```

`BooleanFunction` has a problem here (bug?)

```
BooleanFunction[table1, {a, b}]
(* a *)
```

2nd

```
table2 = {{0, 0} -> 0, {0, 1} -> 1, {1, 0} -> 0};
trueTab2 = Pick[table2, table2[[All, 2]], 1];
boolMin2 = BooleanMinterms[trueTab2[[All, 1]], {a, b}]

(* ! a && b *)
```

and with `BooleanFunction`

```
BooleanFunction[table2, {a, b}]
(* ! a && b *)
```

**addendum**

```
table = {{0, 0} -> 0, {0, 1} -> 1, {1, 0} -> 1};
trueTab = Pick[table, table[[All, 2]], 1]
{{0, 1} -> 1, {1, 0} -> 1}

BooleanMinterms[trueTab[[All, 1]], {a, b}]
(a && ! b) || (! a && b)
```

This code snippet "trueTab" is very helpful if you have 32 bit or more input.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, looks like I would be needing this only. However a question. I checked the term Pick[table2, table2[[All, 2]], 1], and its output is only {{0, 1} -> 1} while it should be the entire table, right?

Comment: @prabhat No, it's right as it is. See my addendum.

Comment: Now I understand, the snippet picks up only those rows where the output is 1, and ignores others. Thanks a lot, this is great solution :)