# How to specify a Boolean Minterm expression using don't cares in Mathematica

Tags: boolean-computation

The [Mathematica Boolean Computation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/BooleanComputation.html) webpage specifies that Mathematica has full support for "don't care" arguments and values. However I don't see any examples demonstrating this functionality. Could someone provide an example, preferably using the BooleanMinterm function?

Answer (score 3):

`BooleanMinterm` doesn't afford the possibility tu use "don't care", but `BooleanFunction` has it :

```
myTruthTableForm[bf_BooleanFunction] := 
  Append[#, bf @@ #] & /@  Tuples[{True, False}, 2] // Boole // 
    Reverse // Grid[#, Dividers -> {{False, False, True}, None}] &;

{#, myTruthTableForm [ReleaseHold[#]]} & /@ {
   HoldForm @ BooleanFunction[{{0, 0} -> 1, {_, 1} -> 0}],
   HoldForm @ BooleanFunction[{{0, 0} -> 1, {0, 1} -> 0}],
   HoldForm @ BooleanFunction[{{0, 0} -> 1, {0, 1} -> 0, {__} -> _ }],
   HoldForm @ BooleanFunction[{{0, 0} -> 1, {0, 1} -> 0, {__} -> 1 }]
   } // Grid[#, Alignment -> Left] &
```

[image]

**Edit**

Note that `BooleanFunction` make some definitives choices about what happen with the "don't care" outputs. Theses choices are not predictible and doesn't correspond to any kind of minimization ("DNF","SOP","CNF","POS" etc..., see a counter example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119453/5467)). Nevertheless real optimisation with "don't care" are available with the third argument of `BooleanMinimize` (there is a example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159245/5467) )