# Simplify a Boolean Algebra expression with don't cares

Tags: boolean-computation

I want to simplify this expression:

```
BooleanMinimize[(A ∧ ¬ B ∧ C ∧ ¬ D) ∨ (A ∧ B ∧ ¬ C ∧ ¬ D) ∨ (A ∧ B ∧ C ∧ ¬ D)]
```

And I get this:

```
(A ∧ B ∧ ¬ D) ∨ (A ∧ C ∧ ¬ D)
```

But using a Karnaugh Map and "don't cares" I get `¬ D`. Is there anyway that I can get similar answer in *Mathematica*?

Comment: can you complete your question with the "don't care cases" ? otherwise we can't guess what you wish.

Comment: I Consider hexadecimal and my "don't cares" are 0-9

Comment: So you mean that A,B,C,D are 10,11,12,13(decimal) in your code ? ,  that is to say constants ? Apparently, you use them as is they where some variables (like x,y,z)

Comment: I mean from (A ∧ ¬ B ∧ C ∧ ¬ D) this "1010" that represent "A" in hexadecimal and some thing like (A ∧  ¬B ∧ ¬C ∧ ¬ D) consider as "don't cares"

Comment: OK, I understand now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An arbitrary function with "don't cares" can be defined using either `BooleanFunction` or `BooleanConvert`, but in those cases, Mathematica makes no effort to find the minimal representation of such a function.

Instead, use `BooleanMinimize` with the optional third argument: an assumed condition on the variables. In your case, you can specify that your "don't cares" are 0-9 by making the condition be `A ∧ (B ∨ C)`.

Then the calculation

```
BooleanMinimize[
  (A ∧ ¬ B ∧ C ∧ ¬ D) ∨ (A ∧ B ∧ ¬ C ∧ ¬ D) ∨ (A ∧ B ∧ C ∧ ¬ D),
  "DNF", 
  A ∧ (B ∨ C)]
```

will produce the desired output of `!D`.

Answer (score 4):

Thank's to @Misha Lavrov (a great thanks !), here is how you can solve the problem :

```
BooleanMinimize[  
    BooleanFunction[{
        {1,0,1,0}-> 1,
        {1,0,1,1}-> 0,
        {1,1,0,0}-> 1,
        {1,1,0,1}-> 0,
        {1,1,1,0}-> 1,
        {1,1,1,1}-> 0
      },{a,b,c,d}],  
    "SOP" (* = "DNF" *),
    BooleanFunction[{
        {1,1,_,_}-> 1, (* all cases above ... *)
        {1,_,1,_}-> 1, (* ... are "do care" *)
        {_,_,_,_}-> 0 (* other cases are "don't care" *)
      },{a,b,c,d}]]
```

> ```
> ! d
> ```

Note :

@Misha Lavrov's comment (just below) was written before I added the third argument to `BooleanMinimize`. At this time there were some "don't care" states in the first `BooleanFunction[...]`